# SIP and TEL links are not working in internet explorer

Tags: typescript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, sip, tel

`Sip` and `Tel` links work a few times initially in ie11 but then stop working.
This works fine on chrome and edge.

The `mailto` works every time without fail on internet explorer. And when I click the `mailto` once when the `Sip` and `Tel` stopped working they start working again.

In .ts:

```
    this.chatUrl = 'sips:' + this.contactInfo.email;
```

In .html:

```
    <a [href]="sanitize(chatUrl)">
        <img style="width:16px; height:16px;" class="contact-image" src="assets/img/IM.png">
    </a>
    <a href="tel:{{contactInfo.telephone}}">
        <i class="contact-image fa fa-phone"></i>
    </a>
```

Comment: what is your actual question? and do you have an example?

Comment: The href links of sip and tel stop working on internet explorer after working for a few times. How can I make them work everytime?

Comment: Also, the mailto works every time without fail on internet explorer. Surprisingly, after the sip and tel links stop working, I click on mailto once and then when I click on sip or tel links they start working again automatically.

Comment: Have you ever tried to use F12 developer tools to check whether it contains some error? can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I do not get any errors but a warning(everytime I click the link images): The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. This even happens when I create a normal html page and run it on ie. The following works intially(approx. 10 times) then stops working                                             <html>
<body>
<a href="sips:tazeen.parvez@domain.com">IM</a>
</body></html>

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce the problem, it seems that the code works well on my side (using IE 11.116.18362.0), try to clear the IE browser cache and history, then re-test the code. If still not working, try to [reset the IE browser setting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings) or upgrade/re-install the IE browser.